# Is there a way to create Pusher App throught API call?

Tags: pusher

I'm developing a multi-tenant web application that uses pusher to send notifications, I need to have one app for each tenant, so I'd like to create a tenenat throught a command and automatically create a pusher app and store its keys

I couldn't find it in Pusher docs, is this an possible option?

What would be my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible at the moment. A possible workaround would be to create a number of apps in advance and then use these credentials as you create tenants.

Additionally, it is possible to create a multi-tenant approach using a single app in Channels. Private/Presence channels require user authentication before the subscription succeeds. This means you could create a channel `private-tenant1` and only allow users from tenant1 to subscribe.

See https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/private-channels for more info.

Comment: I use private channels for notifications, but it is private just per user, using this aproach, would never exist a public channel, all public channel would be a private channel validating the tenant right?

Comment: Yes, if all channels you create have a 'private' or 'presence' prefix then there are no public channels. If you do use this method then you can go one step further and prevent connections from clients that don't subscribe to such a channel using Authorised connections - https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/authorized-connections